# How to disable access to an attached project database

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have a C# Winforms project with an attached database.

Working with `.MDF` database file using SQL Server Express LocalDB.

The application has some usage limits, for example, it has a maximum of records per module. Even if the user deletes some records, those records are flagged as deleted in the database but will never be really deleted in order to count all records (even deleted ones).

After distributing the application to the various users, we are concerned about database access with SSMS and tables/record violation.

Is it possible to prevent users from accessing the database so that users do not delete the records themselves, thus tampering with the accounting of records?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what kind of db in question, maybe SQLServer. Anyway, you can, in most databases, put restrictions on what user is allowed to do.

Comment: Sorry. It's an .mdf database. but can I use SSMS to restrict that?

Comment: Yes, that is possible,

Comment: Can I create a specific user with owner permission? The main point is to allow user to use database but disallow user to login into database using SSMS or other to change table records.

Comment: Usually, application user should not be db owner.

Comment: "Is it possible to prevent users from accessing the database so that users do not delete the records themselves, thus tampering with the accounting of records?"

In short, no.  Any time you put something on a client machine you essentially give them the ability to do anything.  All you can do is make it harder for them.  I think you may need to revisit how you have everything planned out.  Perhaps an in-memory store or a cloud DB would be better?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to prevent users from accessing the database so that users do not delete
> the records themselves, thus tampering with the accounting of records?

Nope. And it is not possible in ANY database technology. Which is why things like SAAS (Software As A Service) is a good choice for scenarios like this. At least you could send a "object created" signal and count that against the license.